# Como comparar una fecha con un DateField Django

Tags: django

no encuentro la manera de filtrar un objeto de mi base de datos con la fecha del dia:

En mi UpdateView:

```
def get_object(self):
    today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return GananciasCortes.objects.get(fecha=today)
```

Me tira el siguiente error:

TypeError at /cierreCaja/
**str** returned non-string (type datetime.date)

El modelo de mi clase es:

```
class GananciasCortes(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(unique=True)
    montoDiario = models.FloatField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['fecha']

def __str__(self):
    return self.fecha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue cambiar el metodo **str** de la clase con la que intentaba matchear:

```
Def str (self):
    return self.fecha.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Esta era la que disparaba el TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias intentar lo siguiente:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
fechaActual = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#salida
print fechaActual
2019-03-14
```

Ahora con esto obtienes la fecha actual, ahora puedes realizar tu queryset:

```
consulta = MiModel.objects.get(fecha=fechaActual)
```

espero y te sirva..suerte..!!

Comment: Hola, probé tu solución, la mía también usaba datetime (llamado date en mi código), como no tenía un registro cargado en mi BD, no encontraba un objeto que matcheara, lo cargue y ahí me volvió a tirar el error que detalle en el post. Osea que Django encuentra el match pero en un proceso posterior intenta ejecutar el método __str__ de mi modelo y falla. La solución fue canbiar dicho método:

Comment: Def __str__ (self):

     return self.fecha.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo del tipo de fecha que necesitas puede ser una [fecha aware (consciente) o naive (ingenua)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts).

puedes utilizar para fecha aware

```
In [1]: from django.utils.timezone import now

In [2]: print(now().date())
2019-03-18

In [2]: print(type(now().date()))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

puedes utilizar para fecha naive

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: print(datetime.datetime.now().date())
2019-03-18

In [3]: print(type(datetime.datetime.now().date()))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Luego simplemente utilizas por ejemplo:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
def get_object(self):
    today = now().date()
    return GananciasCortes.objects.get(fecha=today)
```

Comment: Hola, te agradezco por el enfoque pero la pregunta ya esta respondida, la respondí yo mismo, ya que tenia un problema con un método de mi clase que no devolvía un String. Gracias de todas maneras! Saludos